# Addition efficiency proportional to size of operands?

Tags: performance

Question that just popped into my head, and I don't think I've seen an answer on here. Is the time taken by a binary addition algorithm, proportional to the size of the operands?

Obviously, adding `1101011010101010101101010` and `10110100101010010101` is going to take longer than `1 + 1`, but my question refers more to the smaller values. Is there a negligible difference, no difference, a theoretical difference?

At what point, with these sorts of rudimentary calculations should we start looking into more efficient methods of calculation? ie: Exponentiation by squaring with large exponents for calculating huge powers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### How we see the binary patterns...

`1101011010101010101101010` ***(big)***
`10110100101010010101` ***(medium)***
`1` ***(small)***

#### How a 32bit computer sees the binary patterns...

`00000001101011010101010101101010` ***32bit,***
`00000000000010110100101010010101` ***32bit,***
`00000000000000000000000000000001` ***i'm lovin it***

On a 32bit system, all the above numbers will take the same time (no. of CPU instructions) to be added. As all of them fit within the basic computational block i.e. the 32bit CPU register.

---

#### How a 16bit computer sees the binary patterns...

```
 1
+1 = ?
```

`0000000000000001` ***i'm lovin it***
`0000000000000001` ***i'm lovin it***

```
 00000001101011010101010101101010
+00000000000010110100101010010101 = ?
```

`00000001101011010101010101101010` ***too BIG for me!***
`00000000000010110100101010010101` ***too BIG for me!***

On a 16bit system, as the larger numbers will NOT fit in a 16bit register, it will need an additional pass(to add the significant bits that remain after the first 16LSBs are added).

**Step1: ADD Least significant bits**
`0101010101101010`
`0100101010010101`

**Step2: ADD the rest** (remember carry bit from previous operation)
`000000000000000C`
`0000000110101101`
`0000000000001011`

---

> We **can** start thinking of optimising the mathematical operations on
> numbers once the numbers no longer fit in the basic computation unit
> of the system i.e. the CPU-register.

Modern hardware architectures are developed keeping this in mind and support [**SIMD**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) instructions. Compilers will often employ them (**SSE** on x86, **NEON** on ARM) when they see such a case being made i.e. 128bit decryption logic being run on a 32bit system.

Also instead of checking ONLY the size of the operands, the size of the result also determines whether the system can accomplish the mathematical operation within one step. Not only the operands involved, but the operation being performed needs to be taken into consideration as well.

For example, on a 32bit system, adding two 30bit numbers can be **definitely** carried out using the regular operations as the result is guaranteed to NOT exceed a 32bit register. But multiplying the same two 30bit numbers may result in a number that does NOT fit within 32bits.

In the absence of such a guarantee of being able to store the result in a single computational unit, to ensure validity of the result for all possible values, the architecture(and the compiler) must :

- go the long way i.e. multi-step mathematical operations
  ***or***
- employ SIMD optimisations
  ***or***
- define and implement custom mechanisms
  (like register-pairs *EDX:EAX* to hold the result on x86)

Answer (score 2):

In practice, there's no (or completely negligible) difference between adding different integers that fit in the processor words as that should always be a fixed-time operation.

In theory, the complexity for adding two unsigned integers should be O(log(n)) where n is the bigger of the two. As such, you need to go pretty high before mere additions become a problem.

As for where exactly to draw the line between simple and complex algorithms for computing numbers, I don't have an exact answer. However, the [GMP](http://gmplib.org/) library comes to mind. From what I understand, they've carefully chosen their algorithms and under what circumstances to use each in terms of performance. You may want to look into what they did.

Comment: I was more interested in the last part of the question; at what point should we start employing algorithms that speed up the process of addition, multiplication, exponentiation etc.

Comment: @Chris Derp, I completely missed that part of the question. I've updated my answer with some additional information.

Answer (score 0):

I somewhat disagree with the above answers. It very much depends on the context.

For simple integer arithmetic (for loop counters etc), then on 64bit machines that computation will be done using 64bit general purpose registers (RSI/RCX/etc). In those cases, there is no difference in speed between an 8bit or 64bit addition.

If however you are processing arrays of integers, and assuming the compiler has been able to optimise the code nicely, then yes, smaller is faster (but not for the reason you think).

In the AVX2 instruction set, you have access to 4 integer addition instructions:

```
__m256i _mm256_add_epi8 (__m256i a, __m256i b); // 32 x 8bit
__m256i _mm256_add_epi16(__m256i a, __m256i b); // 16 x 16bit
__m256i _mm256_add_epi32(__m256i a, __m256i b); // 8 x 32bit
__m256i _mm256_add_epi64(__m256i a, __m256i b); // 4 x 64bit
```

You'll notice that all of them operate on 256bits at a time, which means you can process 4 integer additions if you're using 64bit, compared to 32 additions if you are using 8bit integers. (As mentioned above, you'd need to make sure you have enough precision). They all take the same number of clock cycles to compute - 1clk.

There are also other effects of using smaller data types, which are mainly better CPU cache usage, and a reduced number of memory reads/writes.

However, back to your original question on bit-by-bit computation. Prior to the new AVX-512 instruction set, it might not have seemed a little silly. However, the new instruction set contains a ternary logic instruction. With this instruction, it is possible to compute 512 additions on numbers of any bit length fairly easily.

```
inline __m512i add(__m512i x, __m512i x, __m512i carry_in)
{
  return _mm512_ternarylogic_epi32(carry_in, y, x, 0x96);
}
inline __m512i adc(__m512i x, __m512i x, __m512i carry_in)
{
  return _mm512_ternarylogic_epi32(carry_in, y, x, 0xE8);
}

__m512i A[NUM_BITS];
__m512i B[NUM_BITS];
__m512i RESULT[NUM_BITS];
__m512i CARRY = _mm512_setzero_ps();

for(int i = 0; i < NUM_BITS; ++i)
{
  RESULT[i] = add(A[i], B[i], CARRY);
  CARRY = adc(A[i], B[i], CARRY);
}
```

In this particular example (which to be honest, probably has very limited real world usage!), The time it takes to perform the 512 additions, is indeed directly proportional to NUM_BITS.